# No puedo cerrar sesión en Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, cookies, sesiones

Tengo *Symfony 3* configurado para el acceso más básico (`http_basic`). En **security.yml** tengo lo siguiente, en el *firewall*:

```
main:
    security: true
    anonymous: ~
    #De momento, la entrada es por http_basic.
    http_basic: ~

    logout:
        path:   /logout
        target: /
        invalidate_session:   true
        delete_cookies: ['PHPSESSID']
```

También tengo un *provider en memoria*:

```
in_memory:
    memory:
        users:
            user:
                password: $2y$12$cDEE6BJbtj94ZnM7PSimSOx1voqQtq0MebnUOYcg6PmnuVFk5uBaC
                roles: 'ROLE_USER'
            admin:
                password: $2y$12$FLJprSiEP/Bkd2xdJyyBGuHOtWuEUePfkXF54UUFexyPUKPmXlSY.
                roles: 'ROLE_ROOT_ADMIN'
```

Tengo la jerarquía de roles y las denegaciones:

```
#La aplicación usará ROLE_USER y ROLE_ADMIN. Los otros dos se los reserva el desarrollador
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ROOT_ADMIN: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

#Para denegar el acceso si no hay nivel de autenticación.
access_control:
    - { path: /admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /user, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

En el archivo de enrutamiento tengo:

```
logout:
    path: /logout
```

La página principal es de libre acceso, sin denegaciones. Tiene un enlace para ir a la página de administrador. Lo pulso, y me pide los datos de acceso. Los tecleo y me da paso. En la barra inferior de *Symfony* me muestra como usaurio **admin**. Hasta aquí, todo bien.

Ahora pulso el enlace de *logout*, y me reenvía a la página principal, y en la barra inferior me muestra como **anon**. Hasta este punto, todo correcto también.

El problema es que ahora vuelvo a pulsar el enlace para acceder a la página de *admin*, y me da paso sin pedirme la autenticación, y en la barra inferior me vuelve a mostrar como *admin*.

Sin embargo, si borro las *cookies* del navegador, me funciona bien, me vuelve a pedir la autenticación. Esto no debería de ser ser así. La aplicación, no debería recordar que una vez entre como admin. Es decir, una vez en la página principal, como *anon*, ya debería volver a pedir autenticación cada vez que quiera acceder a un área restringinda.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el *logout* limpie realmente los datos de acceso anteriores, y vuelva a pedir autenticación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación, básicamente cuando usas `http-basic` no te deslogueas realmente.

*Documentación de Symfony:* [Security - Logging Out](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/security.html#logging-out)

En inglés:

> Notice that when using `http-basic` authenticated *firewalls*, there is no real way to *log out*: The only way to log out is to have the browser stop sending your **name and password** on every request. Clearing your browser cache or restarting your browser usually helps. Some web developer tools might be helpful here too.

En español:

> Tenga en cuenta que al usar *firewalls* autenticados con `http-basic`, no hay una manera real de cerrar la sesión: La única manera de cerrar la sesión es hacer que el navegador deje de enviar su **nombre y contraseña** en cada solicitud. Borrar la memoria caché de su navegador o reiniciar su navegador generalmente ayuda. Algunas herramientas de desarrollo web pueden ser útiles aquí también.